# Why are JFETs used in voltage-controlled resistors instead of MOSFETs?

Tags: mosfet, jfet, voltage-controlled-resistor

Voltage-controlled resistors (VCRs) are usually implemented using JFETs. JFETs are less common than MOSFETs, so, why not use MOSFETs in VCRs instead?

They both feature an Ohmic region.

Is this because JFETs are more linear in their Ohmic region? I can't find any source mentioning this.

Comment: Please give a specific example - the question is too broad.

Comment: What is a VCR ?

Comment: I'm assuming you don't mean a videocassette recorder, so what do you mean?

Comment: Where in the VCR?

Comment: Sorry, I've just edited now

Answer (score 3):

VCR = "voltage Controlled Resistor"

JFETs are not inherently better than MOSFETs as VCRs. Historically JFETs were more available (especially as discrete transistors) than the very small MOSFETs that would be needed.

In most VCR applications, a resistance of kΩ rather than Ωs is needed; discrete MOSFETs generally are uses as low resistance switches, they are not so suitable.

Also, small discrete MOSFETs are more susceptible to ESD damage when handling; protecting them during manufacturing would significantly increase the cost. In the past discrete MOSFETs were sold with aluminum foil wrappers and special clips to short app pins together until soldered in the board.

Inside ICs, JFETs are not a commonly available component, so MOSFETs are used as VCRs. In modern processes (but not the *most* advanced processes), MOSFETs obey the square-law characteristic that is needed to make a linear resistor reasonably well. It is practical in an IC to make a whole (complex) circuit driving the MOSFET to bias it and linearize it correctly.

Comment: "not a commonly available component" - they're pretty common in JFET-input op amps such as TL071 and used in (typically hidden from the published schematics) bias networks such as in the (bipolar) [LM308](https://i.imgur.com/MaKl7zx.png).

Comment: Most IC technologies that are in production DO NOT HAVE JFETs ==> They are not commonly available in most ICs. Yes, some ICs are available that use JFETs, but they generally tend to be older designs (LM308) is 30+ years old.